# Setting default Content Output Type Header in Axis2

Tags: json, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-api-manager

Is there a way to set the default output type header in AXIS2 say for example to use "Content: application/json" even if the request does not have a content type header sent to the service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a content-type property mediator in each sequence, which can assign the content type.  Here is an example:

```
<property name="ContentType" value="text/xml" scope="axis2"/>
```

Here is documentation on the Axis2 properties [1]. If you wish this to be applied by default, it would depend on what product you're using.  With the api manager, you may edit the velocity-template.xml which is located in [apim home]/repository/resources/api-templates/.  Any changes to this template file will affect all APIs as they are created or republished.

[1]  https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Generic+Properties

Cheers,
Colin

Comment: Thanks @Colin, actually this the one solution I've been planning for a while. Thank you for the additional info on APIM, because that is what I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write an axis2 handler, where set the preferred content-type for all requests/response..